# Swift: Best way to filter an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array with `student objects` and another array with `goodStrudentId`. I need to fetch all the student objects from `students` array following sequence of `goodStrudentId`.
Using multiple forloop i can able to solve this, but i want to learn the best way to solve this issue. My only problem is following sequence of `goodStrudentId`.
Here is a sample code to understand my problem -

```
class Student {
    var s_id : String
    var s_name : String
    init(i: String, n: String) {
        self.s_id = i;
        self.s_name = n;
    }
}

var students = [Student(i: "1",n: "a"),
                Student(i: "2",n: "b"),
                Student(i: "3",n: "c"),
                Student(i: "4",n: "d"),
                Student(i: "5",n: "e")]

var goodStudentsId = ["5","2"]

var goodStudentObject = getGoodStudentObjectUsingId(students:students, gdStudentsId:goodStudentsId)



/*
 Expected answer:
 var goodStudentObject = [Student(i: "5",n: "e"), Student(i: "2",n: "b")]

 */

func getGoodStudentObjectUsingId(students:Array<Student>, gdStudentsId:Array<String>) -> Array<Student>! {
    /*?????? please complete this func*/
    return [];
}
```

Comment: Arrays have a `filter` function; this should be clear after a Google search for the problem. What did you try?

Comment: This site is a great resource for education on higher order swift functions: https://www.weheartswift.com/higher-order-functions-map-filter-reduce-and-more/

Comment: i tried with NSPredicate. i will try with following answer.. no idea why i got negative vote.

Comment: @ConnorNeville i stuck with sequence. thats why i put question here

Comment: @ConnorNeville i know to solve this issue using multiple for loop, but i think this is not the best way to solve this issue

Comment: Best way in what sense? Shortest code? Easy understandable code? Fastest code (which would depend on the size of the arrays and some other parameters)?

Comment: using NSPredicate i have tried to solve this. but the problem is, it doesn't satisfied to follow sequences of second array as you mention your comments @MartinR

Answer (score 1):

```
func getGoodStudentObjectUsingId(students:[Student], gdStudentsId:[String]) -> [Student] {
    return students.filter {
        gdStudentsId.contains($0.s_id)
    }
}
```

Comment: This would return the students in the order as they are in the original array. From the "Expected output" in the question I assume that the result should be ordered according to the ids in gdStudentsId. I may be wrong of course.

Comment: can you help me to provide objective c code as well.

Comment: i tried with swift. its getting wrong sequence as expected